# Calculate order statistics from a matrix in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a matrix in SAS/IML:

```
x = {7 6 3 3 8,
     2 3 5 2 5,
     2 6 4 3 8,
     7 4 8 1 3,
     8 8 6 8 7,
     3 2 6 1 5 };
```

I want to create a new matrix that contains the highest *k* values of each column in `x`. For example, if *k=3*, I want the result matrix to contain:

```
8  8  8  8  8 
7  6  6  3  8
7  6  6  3  7
```

because, for instance, the largest 3 numbers in the first column of `x` are 8, 7, and 7.

I've unsuccessfully tried to figure out how to do this using the **[rank](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/59656/HTML/default/viewer.htm#langref_sect217.htm)** function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Here's a minor revision:

```
do c=1 to ncol(x);   
    r = rank(x[,c]);
    y = x[loc(r>=nrow(x)-k+1), c];
    call sort(y);
    tops[,c] = y;
end;
```

As to avoiding the loop to make it faster, it's not necessary. Even with 10,000 columns, this code runs in a fraction of a second. Try running the following timing code:

```
x = j(500, 10000);
call randgen(x,"normal");
k = 3;
t0=time();
tops = j(k,ncol(x),0);
do c=1 to ncol(x);   
    r = rank(x[,c]);
    y = x[loc(r>=nrow(x)-k+1), c];
    call sort(y);
    tops[,c] = y;
end;
t=time()-t0;
print t;
```

Comment: Great, thanks Rick! Just a note (for other users): before SAS 9.22, you need to use `sort(y,1)` instead of just `sort(y)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial answer I've come up with:

```
k = 3;
tops = j(k,ncol(x),0);
do c=1 to ncol(x);   
    r = rank(x[,c]);
    h=loc(r>=nrow(x)-k+1);
    tops[,c] = x[,c][h];
end;
```

This approach uses a loop, which I'd like to avoid, so please post improvements if possible!

Comment: Also, this doesn't sort the results, which I would like to do.